# Open html page in IE with urllib

Tags: python-3.x, internet-explorer, urllib

I have issues for opening an url using python and urllib in IE, I don't know how to specify to open the url in IE and not Chrome. I can specify it when using webbrowser lib or subprocess, but what I need is to get the HTML code of the desired page without opening. Here what I tried (I know that for subprocess CREATE_NO_WINDOW is for console):

```
url = "myurl.com"
ie = webbrowser.get("C:\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe") #specify browser for webbrowser
ie.open(url)#correctly open it in IE but can t get the HTML code with this lib
        
        subprocess.Popen(
            '"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" %s' 
            % url, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
            # open in IE but open the browser and show the web page

        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url) #always open in chrome
```

If you have any clews for me to solve this problem thank you :)!

Comment: You say what you need is to get the html code of the page without opening, then why you have to open the page in IE? If you only want to scrape the html code, Xim_Vyge's answer can work. You can print `page.content` to get the whole html code of the web page.

Answer (score 1):

So I have this code which gets the html code from site without opening a browser and stores it as XPath data in a tree:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get(link)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

subcode = tree.xpath(x-path)
print("subcodes:\n" + "\n".join(subcode))
```

This uses the requests library and the lxml library. Both can be installed using pip.

This [site](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/) might also help you.